# Matplotlib simple different colour lines graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have a really simple matplot graph and want to change the line colour, when the data is above 50 the line will turn red and below 50 the line colour will be green.

How can I change the line colour, currently I use plot to load in the x & y data then show the graph.

I have tried two methods of loading the data into the graph, but neither of them work and cannot work out what us going with something that seems so simple.

```
# ==========================
# First try at the changing the line colour

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

for i in range(0,100):
   if (i>50):
       plt.plot(i,i, color = 'r') #plot red line
if (i<49):
    plt.plot(i,i, color = 'g') #plot red line

plt.show()

# ==========================
# Second try at the changing the line colour

for i in range(0,50):
   x.append(i)
   y.append(i)

plt.plot(x,y, color='green')

for i in range(50,100):
   x.append(i)
   y.append(i)

plt.plot(x,y, color='red')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest solution is to plot 2 lines, one green and one red. Your second attempt is close to doing this, the problem is that your red line; you plot 0-50 in green, and then you plot 0-100 in red (you kept appending without clearing out the lists first!)

If you use numpy arrays then it's really easy to use conditional slices to generate just the data elements you want. Try this:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)

# Plot all data elements in red
plt.plot(x, y, color='red')

# Replot any y<50 elements in green
plt.plot(x[y < 50], y[y < 50], color='green')

plt.show()
```

Since the second plot is a subset of the first, you get green points hiding the red points. This is visually equivalent to only plotting the red and green points separately, e.g. by using `plt.plot(x[y >= 50], y[y >= 50], color='red')` to only plot the >= 50 elements

Answer (score 1):

Plot separately of each part of a line.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(0,100,100)
y = x

plt.plot(x[:50], y[:50],'r')
plt.plot(x[50:], y[50:], 'g')
plt.show()
```

In your case, it would be

```
i = range(50)
plt.plot(i,i, color = 'r') #plot red line
i = range(50, 100)
plt.plot(i,i, color = 'g') #plot red line

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

**First code:** The reason your first code is not working is because you are trying to plot **individual points** as lines in the for loop. This won't work. Instead what will work in this for loop is a scatter plot or a marker plot. You can achieve this by specifying the marker type, for instance `o` to show dots. You can control the size of markers using `markersize` as shown in the following code below:

```
for i in range(0,100):
    if (i>50):
        plt.plot(i,i, 'o',color = 'r', markersize=2) #plot red dots
    if (i<49):
        plt.plot(i,i, 'o',color = 'g', markersize=5) #plot green dots
```

[image]

**Second code:** The reason your second code doesn't work is because you are using the same lists for appending the data. So the second line (red line) overlaps the first one. The second solution will work if you re-initialize the empty lists as

```
x, y = [], []

for i in range(0,50):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i)

plt.plot(x,y, color='green')

x, y = [], [] # Re-initialize the lists
for i in range(50,100):
    x.append(i)
    y.append(i)

plt.plot(x,y, color='red')
```

[image]